# Dynamic Sitemap with Blog

Tags: wordpress, blog, xml-sitemap

I have a website. My website also have a blog page where I post blog posts. Blogs are posted on WordPress. I want each time I post a new blog, the website XML sitemap updated with that blog post. How can I do this? I can provide you the website URL if it required to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For WordPress use any of these plugin and it will automatically update your blog sitemap

1) https://wordpress.org/plugins/ps-auto-sitemap/

2) https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/